# Cheating in a Pedersen-based auction

Tags: elliptic-curves, pedersen-commitment

Imagine a simple auction made with Pedersen commitments rather than sealed envelopes.

Participant 1 commits their bid, $b_1$, choosing a blinding factor $x_1$ and using publicly known G and H generators. As they do so, the commitment value $C_1$ appears on a public website.

Participant 2 does the same. Again, as they commit their bid, $C_2$ appears on the public website.

As a deadline expires, the auctioneer meets with both participants and asks them to reveal their bids and blinding factors. Whoever committed the lowest bid wins.

If Participant 1 reveals their bid $b_1$ and blinding factor $x_1$ before Participant 2, can Participant 2 construct a new blinding factor $x_2'$ so the commitment $C_2$ can be shown to correspond to a new value of $b_2$ which is lower than $b_1$ (e.g., $b_2' = b_2 - 1$), and thus cheat?

My guess is no, because:

Participant 2 would have to find values of $x_2'$ and $b_2'$ such that $x_2 G - x_2' G = b_2' H - b_2 H$.

Assuming, WLOG, that $b_2'$ is slightly lower than $b_1$, i.e. $b_2' = b_1 - 1$, this becomes

$(x_2 - x_2') G = (b_1 - b_2 - 1) H$.

In exponential form, this could be written as: $g^{x_2-x_2'} = h^ {b_1 - b_2 - 1}$.

Participant knows the right hand side of the equation, because $h$ is known, $b_1$ is the (revealed) bid of the other participant and $b_2$ is its own original bid.

However, without finding the discrete log of $h$ in base $g$, I don't see how Participant 2 could cheat.

Am I right or am I missing something?

Comment: @knaccc Feel free to expand that into an answer

Comment: "Assuming, WLOG, that $b_2'$ is slightly lower than $b_1$, i.e. $b_2' = b_2 - 1$..."; this is where your argument (which is correct up to this point) veers off.  Instead, we have $(x_2 - x'_2)G = (b_2 - b'_2)H$ or $ (b_2 - b'_2)^{-1} (x_2 - x'_2) G = H$; and the LHS is computable...

Comment: @poncho I think it should be (x2-x2')G=(b2'-b2)H, not (b2-b2')H. Anyway, you're saying that, because you can write (x2-x2')G = (b2-b2') H, x2'G =x2G + (b2'-b2) H, whose RHS is  known, which means that I can finally reveal an x2' which would prove a different value, thus cheating. Is this correct? I'm not sure if I should answer my own question or let you expand your remark into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is a possible attack which relies on a specific construction of $C_2$.

Let $C_2=C_1 + x_2G + (n-1)H $, $n$ being the order of the elliptic curve on $Z_p$.

Note that, by definition of elliptic curve order, $nH = O$, where $O$ is the neutral element of $Z_p$, i.e. $P+O=P$ for any point $P$ on the curve.

Therefore, we can rearrange $C_2$ as follows: $C_2=C_1 + x_2G + pH - H$.

Substituting $pH = O$, we get:
$C_2=C_1 + x_2G - H$.

By definition of Pedersen commitment, $C_1 = x_1 G + b_1 H$. Therefore,

$C_2=x_1G + b_1 H + x_2G - H = (x_1+x_2)G+ (b_1-1)H$.

This shows that $C_2$, in its own particular construction we saw earlier, is in fact the commitment of $(b_1-1)$ (smaller than $b_1$ !) with a blinding factor $x_2'=(x_1+x_2)$.

Since Participant 2 already knows $b_1$, $x_1$, $x_2$, they can claim their commitment was for $b_1-1$, which is lower than the other bid, and win.

EDIT

To avoid excessive comment proliferation, I summarize here some important points that were brought so far by @knaccc.

Ultimately, the reason why this kind of attack works is the additive property of Pedersen commitments. An attacker can exploit the fact that $C(x_1+x_2,b_1+b_2)=C(x_1,b_1)+C(x_2,b_2)$ (with $C(x_1,b_1)$ known) to plausibly claim their commitment was for something else which is mathematically related to the victim's bid *and* blinding factor.

Possible mitigations include:

1. revealing the blinding factor but only after disclosing both the commitment and the hash of the blinding factor: $(C_i,h(b_i))$. As long as the hash function is cryptographically secure, an attacker shouldn't be able to find $b_i$ from its hash. And if they cannot mathematically relate their own blinding factor to $b_i$, the attack doesn't work because Pedersen commitments are additive w.r.t *both* terms;
2. not using homomorphic commitments at all.

Comment: @knaccc I think the point with x_1+x_2 is that it works even if you publish the commitment before knowing the other bid. C_1+ x_2G contains x_1G+x_2G, which one can treat as a commitment with blinding factor x_1+x_2. Not sure if it can be generalized.

Comment: @knaccc $C_2=C_1+x_2G+(n−1)H$. $C_1$ is known, $x_2$ is generated by Participant 2, $n$ and $H$ are known parameters of the elliptic curve setup.

Comment: @knaccc yes, committing (C,h(x)) would definitely work with any solid cryptographic hash function.

Comment: An even better approach would be to not use Pedersen commitments at all, because they are homomorphically additive, and that's a harmful property in this scenario. Therefore, just use a hash commitment of the form "H(blinding factor || bid)", where the protocol requires the blinding factor to be of a pre-defined bit length (to prevent malleability)

Comment: "to plausibly claim their commitment was for something else" <- This isn't accurate. The reason that the attack works is not because the commitment is opened to a different value, and that Pedersen commitments don't really commit. Rather, it works because it's trivially possible to declare a commitment which is a delta of the value of another commitment, even if the value of the other commitment is unknown. Later on, knowledge of the other participant's blinding factor is used to allow the attacker to determine the blinding factor of their delta commitment.